# Converting LINQ to a more verbose expression using ReSharper?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, resharper

I notice ReSharper suggests I can "compress" my code using LINQ, is there a way to "uncompress" them? I have a lot of colleagues who use LINQ expressions. Have yet to get using the way it's written.

E.g

```
var cp = currentCase.CaseParts;
foreach (var t in cp)
{
    if (t.Part == null || t.CasePartRole == null || t.Part.Id != part.Id || t.CasePartRole.Id != role.Id)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (!t.Period.IsActive)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Case part already exist. CaseId: {currentCase.Id}, role: {role.Title}, name: {part.GetName()}");
    }
}
```

Is compressed to the LINQ expression:

```
var cp = @case.CaseParts;
if (cp.Where(t => t.Part != null && t.CasePartRole != null && t.Part.Id == part.Id && t.CasePartRole.Id == role.Id).Any(t => !t.Period.IsActive))
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Case part already exist. CaseId: {@case.Id}, role: {role.Title}, name: {part.GetName()}");
}
```

What if I only had the LINQ expression?

Comment: did you try hit Alt+Enter to get the suggestions? I suppose there is something like "convert to loop".

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get used to LINQ syntax. The second code snippet is far more expressive (declarative) than the first, imperative one. Also, the second expression offers a chance to do the evaluation database-side if `cp` would be an `IQuryable` from, f.e., Entity Framework.

Comment: I would even go a step further and use only `Any` - but I'm not expecting automatic code generators to be able to do that, not even ReSharper...

Comment: The sooner you'll get used to the linq syntax the better. It's an industry standard by now and you should be comfortable using it as a professional .net developer.

Comment: Alt+Enter didn't work. 

I'll just have to get used to it. Thanks guy